# Dynamic Plot of multiple Disk Graphics

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate, dynamic

I want to plot multiple disks with disk-coordinates and disk-radii from two dynamically updated lists. I think there should be an easy way to do that but I dont get it. Thx for your help!

```
Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 100, 1}] 
List1 = Dynamic[RandomInteger[40, {x, 2}]](*disk coordinates*)
List2 = Dynamic[RandomInteger[4, x]] (*disk radii*)
Dynamic[Graphics[Table[{Disk[List1, List2]}, {x}]]] (*doesnt work*)
Dynamic[Graphics[MapThread[Disk[#1, #2] &, {List1, List2}]]] (*doesnt work*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 coords = RandomInteger[{5, 95}, {x, 2}];
 radii = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, x];
 Show[
  Graphics[Table[Disk[coords[[n]], radii[[n]]], {n, 1, Length[coords]}]],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}
  ], {x, 1, 100, 1}]
```

[image]